# How to Connect Remote MS Access DataBase in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

I Want to connect MS Access Database in Visual Studio 2019 which is on Virtual Machine. So How To connect it ?

I had try to connect .bds file which is for MS Access DataBase .And those .bds DataBase Files are On Virtual Machine . so how to take those .bds database Path for connecting database in visual studio  [so how to take DataBase Path which Are on Virtual MAchine ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8TyC.png)

Comment: All examples I have seen uses files. While the file could be on a network, there are as far as I know no network service available. I would seriously consider migrating your data to an actual SQL database, I have had way to many issues with access to recommend it for anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.